# Est-ce qu'il y a une difference entre un voyageur et un passager?

Tags: vocabulaire, transports

Mon manuel dit qu'un voyageur est pour le train et le car (commercial bus), mais un passager est pour la voiture, le bus, et l'avion...

C'est vraiment la différence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ça n'a rien à voir avec le véhicule.

Un voyageur est une personne qui voyage.
Une personne qui prend le train chaque matin pour aller travailler n'est pas un voyageur.
Ce n'est pas lié à un véhicule. On peut être un voyageur à pied.

Un passager est une personne passive dans un véhicule. Pas le conducteur ni le personnel.

Certaines compagnies appellent leur clients « passagers », d'autres « voyageurs », d'autres autrement.
C'est un choix marketing lié à chaque entreprise. Ce n'est pas propre à la langue française.

Comment: Merci! Alors, pourquoi le textbook utilise cette définition?

Comment: Une personne qui prend le train chaque matin est un voyageur lors de ses déplacements.

Comment: Parce qu'ils ne veulent pas admettre ne pas le comprendre :-)? Le textbook n'est pas toujours ecrit par un expert.

Answer (score 5):

[**Voyageur**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voyageur) (qui voyage) et [**passager**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passager) (de passage) sont souvent synonymes, mais ces mots ne sont pas toujours interchangeables. Voyageur est associé à un déplacement alors que passager ( = qui n'est que temporairement dans un véhicule) s'oppose à équipage ( = personnel permanent d'un bateau ou d'un avion).

L'une des définitions de [passager](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/passager) dans le TLFi est la suivante :

> B. − Substantif. Personne transportée à bord d'un véhicule, qu'elle ait eu à acquitter ou non un prix de passage.
>   1. [Sur un bateau ou un avion]
>   …
>   2. − Par analogie. [Dans un train, un autobus, une voiture; par opposition à conducteur]
>   …
>   **Rem**. Dans ces emplois, on dit plutôt *voyageur*.

On voit donc que l'utilisation de **passager** pour des moyens de transport ne disposant pas d'un équipage mais d'un conducteur est une extension du sens original et que **voyageur** lui est préféré. Le manuel de français va un peu dans le sens de cette recommandation, mais pas exactement.